Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: WorkerConfig for runtime: python not found
I have Function App of Python v2 and docker based.
function_app.py:
import logging
import time
import azure.functions as func
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.schedule(schedule="0 * * * * *", arg_name="myTimer", run_on_startup=True,
              use_monitor=False) 
def timer_trigger(myTimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    if myTimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')
    
    chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get('http://selenium.dev/')
    assert "Selenium" in browser.title
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.quit()

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function executed.')

local.settings.json:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"
  }
}

requirements.txt:
azure-functions
chromedriver-autoinstaller

Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.11
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
COPY . /home/site/wwwroot

error:  Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: WorkerConfig for runtime: python not found.
Errors in VS Code:

1st time deployment is successful but I didn't get the timer trigger function in the azure portal.
2nd time deployment:
3:07:49 PM fa-pyv2d-ci-001: Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
3:07:50 PM fa-pyv2d-ci-001: Deployment successful. deployer = ms-azuretools-vscode deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build.
3:08:11 PM fa-pyv2d-ci-001: Syncing triggers...
3:08:14 PM fa-pyv2d-ci-001: Querying triggers...
3:08:19 PM fa-pyv2d-ci-001: No HTTP triggers found.

3rd time deployment: - Failed
3:18:51 PM fa-pyv2d-ci-001: Zip package size: 2.83 kB
3:18:54 PM fa-pyv2d-ci-001: Fetching changes.
3:18:55 PM fa-pyv2d-ci-001: Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/47acfecb-1a01-482a-a933-8a41bf22c5e4.zip (0.00 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
3:19:20 PM fa-pyv2d-ci-001: Deployment failed.


Is your code running locally fine?

Yes. Its running locally good. Deployment failing to azure function app

Are you deploying function directly to your function app from VS code? without using Docker?

Yes, deploying from vs code without using docker commands.

Just want to confirm, you want  deploy a normal Function app or Docker function. because if you don't want docker function then Dockerfile won't be required.

It won't work on Azure because Function run inside a virtual environment/container in which chrome or any bowser is installed, it will still throw error after successful deployment. image

It's a docker-based function only with the prog. lang is python v2 and will the browsers not work in the containers or virtual environments?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

In docker you need to use chrome as headless mode
This is how I ran my code in docker and deployed.
function_app.py:
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import time
from pyppeteer import launch
import chromedriver_autoinstaller
app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.schedule(schedule="0 */5 * * * *", arg_name="myTimer")
async def timer_trigger(myTimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    if myTimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    browser = await launch(headless=True, args=['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'])
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('http://selenium.dev/')
    title = await page.title()
    assert "Selenium" in title
    time.sleep(60)
    await browser.close()
    logging.info('Python timer trigger function executed using pyppeteer.')


Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.11

# Install system dependencies for Chrome and ChromeDriver
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    wget \
    unzip \
    xvfb \
    libxi6 \
    libgconf-2-4 \
    fonts-liberation \
    libappindicator3-1 \
    libasound2 \
    libatk-bridge2.0-0 \
    libatk1.0-0 \
    libcups2 \
    libdbus-1-3 \
    libnspr4 \
    libnss3 \
    libxss1 \
    lsb-release \
    xdg-utils \
    libgbm1 \
    --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Chrome
RUN wget -q -O /tmp/chrome.deb https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb \
    && dpkg -i /tmp/chrome.deb || apt-get install -fy \
    && rm /tmp/chrome.deb

# Set display port to avoid crashes
ENV DISPLAY=:99

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
COPY . /home/site/wwwroot

To deploy Function using docker :

Build your docker file.
Push it to Azure Container registry
Enable Admin User in Container Registry
Select the pushed image:tag from Azure Container registry in Azure Function App--> Deployment Centre

OUTPUT:

